# UWP Map Control with animated Custom Layers

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-maps

I am trying to animate custom layers within my application, using the MapControl.  I am able to set each layer and view them, however, I am not able to animate them smoothly.

Previously, I used Bing Maps SDK, which I had a timer set to toggle the visibility of each layer at 500ms. This technique does not work with the MapControl, as it causes a blinking occurrence (my assumption being that the layer is discarded and needs to redownload each toggle).

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, this is not a well supported scenario. Better support for animated tile layers is a feature under consideration for future release.
Right now, what you're doing is the best way to go, and yes the tile layers will flash. Setting the flag to not animate the tile layer will help a bit.

Comment: How does the stock Weather application animate the radar tile layers? or are they not using the MapControl ?

Comment: The weather application is hosting a web view and using the V8 Bing Maps HTML control. The V8 control has better animated tile layer support at the moment.